# Positive reals $a,b,c$ satisfy $2a\sqrt{a}+3b\sqrt{b}+18c\sqrt{c}=2022$ and minimize $a^3+b^3+c^3$. Find $a+b+c$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, systems-of-equations, recreational-mathematics

> The positive real numbers $a,b,c$ satisfy $2a \sqrt{a}+3b \sqrt{b}+18c \sqrt{c} = 2022$ and make $a^3+b^3+c^3$ the smallest possible. Find $a+b+c$.

Right now, I'm stuck on where to start. Squaring both sides of the equation didn't seem to get me anywhere. Can I have a direction to head in please? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Even when you're completely stumped, you can provide useful context. If this is a textbook exercise, tell us the topic(s) covered so far that seem relevant. If it's an online challenge or contest, give the intended audience. Sometimes, just "thinking out loud" about things you know can get you going, and it keeps others from explaining things you already understand. ... In any case, the more you can show that you're personally invested in finding a solution, the more likely it is that others will become invested in helping you with the search.

Comment: What is the source of this problem? The $2022$ may lead some to suspect it's from an on-going contest.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow this guidelines to get help in this site. For example, see the section: **Avoid "no clue" questions**: `Too many questions begin or end with "I don't even know how to begin with this problem". While this may be true (you may genuinely have no idea how to approach the problem), it is still not a valid reason to limit your post to the statement of the problem without any mention of your own thoughts ...`

Comment: I fixed it now...can you please take a second look? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: You can actually solve $a,b,c$.

Hint2: Use Cauchy-Schwartz inequality to get the minimizing $a,b,c$.

Comment: This user is asking questions from a test for a math summer camp. awesomemath.org. His history of questions are from that test with slightly altered numbers. Please refrain from answering them until the test is over. (march 27 2022)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $2022^2  = (2a\sqrt{a}+ 3b\sqrt{b}+18c\sqrt{c})^2\le (2^2+3^2+18^2)(a^3+b^3+c^3)$. The min value of $a^3+b^3+c^3$ is $\dfrac{2022^2}{2^2+3^2+18^2}=12,132.$ And achieving this value requires that $\dfrac{2}{a\sqrt{a}}=\dfrac{3}{b\sqrt{b}}=\dfrac{18}{c\sqrt{c}}\implies \dfrac{4}{a^3}=\dfrac{9}{b^3}=\dfrac{324}{c^3}= \dfrac{337}{12,132}\implies a =\sqrt[3]{\dfrac{4\cdot 12,132}{337}}=\sqrt[3]{144}$. Can you find the other values? and the sum $a+b+c$?

Comment: So then to make $a^2+b^2+c^2$ as small as possible, the two would be equated? If so, would it be $2022^2  = (2a\sqrt{a}+ 3b\sqrt{b}+18b\sqrt{c})^2 = (2^2+3^2+18^2)(a^3+b^3+c^3)?$ Thank you!

Comment: So then $a^3+b^3+c^3=12132,$ and then what would I do?

Comment: help...please???

Comment: I just edited it. There is a small part you can complete in finding $a+b+c$.

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

$ a^3 + b^3 +c^3 \geq 3abc (AM \geq GM) $ with the equality holding true only when $ a^3 = b^3 = c^3$. Since the minimum value of AM($ a^3 + b^3 +c^3$) is GM, $ a^3 = b^3 = c^3$ for this question. so a=b=c

So $23a\sqrt{a} = 2022$

a=250.013

a+b+c=3a=750.039